# jQuery ButtonSet() Hover State Override

Tags: jquery-ui

I have been tooling around with this all day and can't figure it out...

I have a list of buttons (utilizing the jQuery UI buttonset() functionality) and I am wanting to keep the `ui-active` class even after I hover off of a button, but for some reason, jQuery UI functionality keeps removing the class and erases the highlight from the button (this is bad because the user then wouldn't know what button they are on).

Here is the code so far:

```
function showSection(sectionIndex){
    $('.listSection').hide();
    $('#listSection' + sectionIndex).show();

    $('.listSectionHeader.ui-state-active').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
    });

    $('#listSectionHeader' + sectionIndex).addClass('ui-state-active');
}

var buttons = $( "#listHeader a" );

        $.each(buttons, function(){
            $(this).bind('mouseleave.button', function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))
                    return;
            });
        });
```

Comment: can you also post your html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4yamQ/ ? Would require an extra class in the css such as:

```
ui-state-active,
ui-mycustomclass
{
jquery ui styling...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution helped me come to a fix for my problem